# How Do i include function from different files? C

Tags: c

I have a problem. I have an exercise...with prototypes and functions, and everything works.But when i want to put the prototypes and the functions in a different source file, then everything change...

To better understand, this is what i have to do in details...

create a file mydates.h to hold the prototypes for your functions, as well as a source file mydates.c (that includes the header file mydates.h) to hold the function definitions. Then change the program from exercise 8.3 to use the functions declared in mydates.h and defined in mydates.c.

As I said ex. 8.3 works (functions,prototypes and main(void) in a single file) but when I divide them,they don't work anymore...here are my files..

9.3mydates.h

```
#ifndef _SET_H_
#define _SET_H_


/*PROTOTYPES*/
int promptYear(void); /* asks for a year and returns the year number read frokm the standard input */
int leapYear(int); /* return true (1) if the year passed in as a parameter is a leap year */
void computus(int); /* procedure for calculating the date of Easter in a given year */
int findWeekday(int,int,int); /* return the day of the week for a given date as a number between 0 (Sunday) and 6 (Saturday) */

#endif
```

---

9.3mydates.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"9.3mydates.h"

int promptYear(void)
{
    printf("Give me a year bitch: ");
    scanf("%d", &year);
    fflush(stdin);  
    return year;    
}   



int leapYear(int year)
{
    int x=1; /* x=1 -> leap year */

        if(year%4==0)
        {
            if(year<1582)
                x=1;
            else
            {
                if(year%100 == 0)
                {
                    if(year%400==0)
                        x=1;

                    else
                        x=0;
                }
                else x=1;
            }       
        }
        else x=0;
        return x;
}


void computus(year)
{
        int a = year%19;
        int b = year/100;
        int c = year%100;
        int d = b/4;
        int e = b%4;
        int f = (b+8)/25;
        int g = (b-f+1)/3;
        int h = (19*a +b-d-g+15)%30;
        int i = c/4;
        int k = c%4;
        int L = (32+2*e+2*i-h-k)%7;
        int m = (a=11*h+22L)/451;

        month = (h+L-7*m+114)/31;
        day = ((h+L-7*m+114)%31)+1;

        printf("The date for Easter in %4d is %02d/%02d/%04d.\n",year,day,month,year);
}

int findWeekday(int day,int month, int year)
{
   int weekday=0; /* variable for storing the weekday */
   year=year+month;
   year=year+day;
   weekday=year%7;
   return weekday;
}
```

---

9.3.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"9.3mydates.c"
#include"9.3mydates.h"

int cDay=0,cMonth=0; /* global variable to hold the result for the Easter day calculation */
int month,day;
int main(void)
{
   int year=0;

   year=promptYear();

   computus(year);

   printf("Easter day %04d, the %02d/%02d/%02d is a ",year,cDay,cMonth,year);
   switch(findWeekday(cDay,cMonth,year))
   {
     case 0: printf("Sunday");
             break;
     case 1: printf("Monday");
             break;
     case 2: printf("Tuesday");
             break;
     case 3: printf("Wednesday");
             break;
     case 4: printf("Thursday");
             break;
     case 5: printf("Friday");
             break;
     case 6: printf("Saturday");
             break;
  }
  printf(".\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How are you compiling the program?

Comment: I'm compiling the program with RedHead with the follow line:

clang -c 9.3mydates.c

to create a library object file and then to create a true library...but it doesn't work...the errors popping up are in 9.3.mydates.c and they are all related to undecleared variable...for example 

9.3mydates.c:7:15: error: ‘year’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to include 93mydates.c, you want to compile it as a module, so get rid of this line:

```
#include"9.3mydates.c"
```

And then add 9.3mydates.c to your compiler command line or project.

Comment: i removed it, but still, it doesn't work...maybe im compiling it in the wrong way, i don't know...

Shouldn't I compile it with the line:

clang -c 9.3mydates.c 

to create a library object file and then to create a true library...but it doesn't work...the errors popping up are in 9.3.mydates.c and they are all related to undecleared variable...for example 9.3mydates.c:7:15: error: ‘year’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: @StefanoFeltre: Add the extra information about how you are compiling the code to the question.  You should not include `.c` files (normally).  You should include header (`.h`) files.  You can compile `9.3mydates.c` into `9.3mydates.o` with `clang -c 9.3mydates.c`.  You can compile `9.3.c` to `9.3.o` similarly.  You can then link the two with `clang -o 9.3 9.3.o 9.3mydates.o`.  You should be compiling with more options: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` would be a good start.  (Using `-Weverything` is too much for you as yet.)

Answer (score 2):

`year` is not found because it's not defined. :-)

```
int promptYear(void)
{
    int year; /* you have to define the variable! */

    printf("Give me a year buddy: ");
    scanf("%d", &year);
    fflush(stdin);  
    return year;    
}
```

By the way: this **must never** show up in production code! Is this a home work assignment?

Comment: What do you mean by this? Btw yes it's a home assignment ^^" If u mean about what i wrote in the printf i realized it after i published it ^^"

Comment: @StefanoFeltre The code doesn't contain any error checks, check of boundaries etc. For example one could easily input a large number for `year` which would overwrite internal memory and would render the resulting behaviour undefined aka dangerous. Have a look at this page: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT05-C.+Do+not+use+input+functions+to+convert+character+data+if+they+cannot+handle+all+possible+inputs